# Load External JavaScript on Desktop Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I have went through a ton of answers, and I can not get anything to work for me. Please be patient and specific as I am a newbie when it comes to using JavaScript.

I am attempting to get an external JavaScript file to load on Desktop only. Below is the code I am currently using, but it is not working. Can someone please help me achieve this.

```
<script>
(function() {
if( window.innerWidth > 600 ) {
    var theScript = document.createElement('script');
        theScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        theScript.src = 'www.siteminds.net/m/1.6/mind_loader.php?pid=y2w6z8B3N31&cast_id=v1532315&autoplay=1&avname=jackie&wc=1&avnum=15&band_type=av';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(theScript, s);
}
})();
</script>
```

I am placing this code in the head section, however, the script is not running.

The website is responsive using respond.js. I also added enquire.js in an attempt to use that method (which I also couldn't get to work)

Answer (score 4):

Probably, the main issue is that you must include the protocol on the URL so:

```
'www.siteminds.net/m/1.6/mind_loader.php?pid=y2w6z8B3N31&cast_id=v1532315&autoplay=1&avname=jackie&wc=1&avnum=15&band_type=av'
```

needs to be:

```
'http://www.siteminds.net/m/1.6/mind_loader.php?pid=y2w6z8B3N31&cast_id=v1532315&autoplay=1&avname=jackie&wc=1&avnum=15&band_type=av'
```

---

Your code could also fail if there were not already some script tags.  This version is not vulnerable to that:

```
<script>
(function() {
if( window.innerWidth > 600 ) {
    var theScript = document.createElement('script');
    theScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    theScript.src = 'http://www.siteminds.net/m/1.6/mind_loader.php?pid=y2w6z8B3N31&cast_id=v1532315&autoplay=1&avname=jackie&wc=1&avnum=15&band_type=av';

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(theScript);
}
})();
</script>
```

Note: a test for `innerWidth > 600` is not even close to a fail-proof way to detect a desktop installation as even a tablet in landscape mode will pass that test.

Comment: More then anything, I just need it to not run on mobile. Tablet is ok. I tried your suggestion and script is not running at all.

Comment: @kp_marz- What errors do you see in the console?  And, why is it taking you four days to respond?  Things don't work very well here if a communication happens once every four days.

Comment: Sorry about my timing. Either way, I found a solution that works. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

This is what ended up working for me.

```
<script>
var width = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;

if ( width > 600) {
document.write('<script src="//www.siteminds.net/m/1.6/mind_loader.php?pid=y2w6z8B3N31&cast_id=v1532315&autoplay=1&avname=jackie&wc=1&avnum=15&band_type=av" async><\/script>');
}
</script>
```